# Ember removes element from DOM after creating it, and jQuery can not find it

Tags: ember.js

I have this wrapper around `Ember.Select`, to activate `Select2` features:

```
App.Select2SelectView = Ember.Select.extend({
    prompt: 'Please select...',
    classNames: ['input-xlarge'],

    didInsertElement: function() {
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'processChildElements');
    },

    processChildElements: function() {
        this.$().select2({
            // do here any configuration of the
            // select2 component
            escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; } // we do not want to escape markup since we are displaying html in results
        });
    },

    willDestroyElement: function () {
        this.$().select2('destroy');
    }

});
```

Sometimes I need to make a drop-down invisible, and I do it like this:

```
{{#if cityVisible}}
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">City</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {{view SettingsApp.Select2SelectView
                id="city-id"
                contentBinding="currentCities"
                optionValuePath="content.city"
                optionLabelPath="content.city"
                selectionBinding="controller.selectedCity"
                prompt="Select a city"}}
            <i class="help-block">Select the city for your geographical number</i>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

But whenever the drop-down is invisible, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'select2' of undefined
```

I guess the element is inserted, but then removed by `Ember` from the `DOM` (bound property `cityVisible`), so that `jQuery` is not able to find it?

What can I do to avoid that error message? I do not want to make the view visible/invisible, I want to keep the whole `control-group` under the `cityVisible` control.

Comment: just added `.` in front of the css class name, did forget it , and also a demo, sorry :)

Comment: Didn't fall for that one! :)

Comment: cool :) check the demo anyway, it is self explanatory ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviuor that ember removes the view, as a workaround you could do the following:

### HTML

```
<div {{bindAttr class="view.cityVisible::hideCities"}}>
  <div class="control-group">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.hideCities {
  display: none;
}
```

Remove the `{{#if}}` around the html block, and wrap it with a `div` instead on which you set a css class which contains `display: none;` you could use the `cityVisible` or a different property in your view or controller and set it to true/false to toggle it's visibility. This mecanisnm should leave your html markup in the DOM an thus available for jQuery. Note that if your `citiesVisible` property lives in your controller then remove the `view.` prefix from `view.citiesVisible` to be only `citiesVisible`, this depends on your setup.

See demo [here](http://jsbin.com/odosoy/23/edit).

Hope it helps.